# Enterprise Architect - Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers -2147217900 / '80040E14'

Tags: mysql, odbc, enterprise-architect

I am setting up Sparx's Enterprise Architect to work in centralized mode using:

- EA version 10.0.1007
- Database: MySQL CE version 5.6.13.1
- Connector: mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.2-win32.msi

I've successfully setup the database and connector in Data Sources. Test connection is working.

On the first project, EA requesting to import project, in which I imported EABase.eap from C:\Program Files (x86)\Sparx Systems\EA. This is success also.

I click the Add New Model from Pattern, choose the Name, and click OK, then I got the following error (shown three times):

[image: EA error ODBC]

If I close the EA and then reopen, the packages and diagrams are still there, meaning they are saved to MySQL database.

The error is also shown whenever I first clicked on the diagram.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the correct ODBC driver?

32 vs 64 bit is relevant here.
You should use the 32bit driver even if you are on 64bit Windows.

If you are using a 64-bit operating system (see [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/10/projects_and_teams/setupapostgresqlodbcdriver.html)):

• Enterprise Architect requires 32-bit ODBC drivers to connect to a repository through ODBC; to set up the ODBC configuration on 64-bit clients, run the 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator from C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

• You can quickly load the correct 32-bit ODBC Data Source Administrator by selecting Tools | ODBC Data Sources in the Enterprise Architect menu bar

Also: Did you check the two checkboxes as described in the installation of the driver? (Select the Return matched rows instead of affected rows and Allow big result sets checkboxes.) See [here](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/setupmysqlodbcdriver.html) for a detailed description

Comment: Yes, I used 64-bit Windows and I've installed the 32-bit driver. I've also checked those two options

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while I migrated some projects from eap files to a MySQL database.

The problem is caused by `Cast(Partition as Signed);`

The Enterprise Architect uses a column name "**Partition**" but it is a reserved key word since version 5.6.2 (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html#idm140349563775776)) of the MySQL dbms.

Switch to the MySQL version 5.5.46 (x64) and the error will disappear.