# connect to postgresql from enterprise architect

Tags: postgresql, connection, database-connection, enterprise-architect

I've Enterprise Architect v12 and I want to use its Database builder in order to create a live connection between it and a postgresql database.

This is what I've done:

- I've downloaded and installed PostgreSQL 9.5
- During installation I've installed with StackBuilder `Npgsql v2.2.4.3-2` and `psqlODBC (64 bit) v09.03.0400-1`.
- I've started `pgAdmin III` and I can connect to my local database. I've created a new one without problems.
- I've created in EA a new project: in technology I've selected `Database` and `Data model: PostgreSQL`.
- In `DataModel -> Tables -> Tables` I've added a table `Table1` and I've created a column `id` (varchar and primary key)
- In the same table I've added a Datatabase connection `Database connection 1`.
- I double click on `Database connection 1` and then I select `ODBC based database`. Then click OK

At this point I'm not able to select my postgresql database. The data origin window (I don't know if it's the right name I've the italian version of windows) gives me two tabs: File origin data and computer origin data. In the first case inside the postgresql data folder that I've selected during installation I don't find anything useful, while in the second case I can see only `Excel files` and `MS Access Database`. If I click on `New` button I can select the data origin only for the current user and in the list I can't see postgresql (SQL Server, Microsoft paradox, etc).

What I'm doing wrong? How can I read my posgresql database from EA?

Comment: see here for my answer to a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904058/enterprise-architect-microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-odbc-drivers-2147217900/23908013#23908013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enterprise Architect only connects to 32 bit ODBC datasources.

You can access the 32 bit ODBC manager from within EA from `Tools|ODBC Data Sources` or directly in windows from `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: See http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/8.0/projects_and_teams/connecttoapostgresqlreposi.html

Comment: Re-running StackBuilder and adding the 32 bit version of the driver solved the problem. Thanks.

Comment: helped me yesterday